# How to compare two column value of two row in a single table using sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have table `employee`

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| id           | e_name |  leder_id  |
+--------------+--------+------------+
| 1            | abc    | 2          |
| 2            | def    | 4          |
| 3            | ghi    | 2          |
| 4            | jkl    | 1          |
| 5            | mno    | 3          |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

...and I want output like this by using SQL. where every `e_name` has a leader and their `leder_id` is given.

```
+--------------+---------+
|e_name        | l_name | 
+--------------+--------+
| abc          | def    | 
| def          | jkl    | 
| ghi          | def    | 
| jkl          | abc    | 
| mno          | ghi    | 
+--------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the *SELF JOIN*

```
SELECT 
       e.e_name, el.e_name as l_name 
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN employee el on el.id = e.leder_id
```

In case some employee has no any leader use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: Probably best to alias the `SELECT` columns to avoid result set name clashes.

Comment: hello Yogesh, how to create new column name "l_name", the first table is the avilable table and I want output as the second table.

Comment: @ShubhamMishra... just rename the alise as you would like to display.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :

```
SELECT
    e.e_name as e_name ,
    l.e_name as l_name        
FROM
    employee e,
    employee l
WHERE
    e.leder_id  = l.id
```